# How to fetch data from multiple tables using Join and where clause

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have written a simple symfony controller where I have two table known as specialtyarea and physician.

this is the basic structure of the table

```
specialtyarea
-----------------
id | name       |
-----------------
1  | dentist    |
2  | physician  |
```

Physician table is related to `specialtyarea` as shown:

```
Physician
--------------------
id | name | specfk |
--------------------
1  | John  | 1     |
2  | Doe   | 2     |
3  | Ann   | 2     |
```

I am trying to fetch all the physician where specialty area is 2

This is my snippet of code

```
public function getAllPhysicianAction($specId)
{
     $id = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:SpecArea')
        ->find($specId); //assuming that this returns all the id from the specialty table

    $allPhysician = $id->getPhysician()->...   //kind of lost here    
}
```

How can I retrieve all the records from the physician table using the specialty Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can just call findBy on your physician repository.

```
/**
 * @Route("/physicians/{specId}", name="getAllPhysician")
 */
public function getAllPhysicianAction($specId)
{
    $allPhysician = $this->getDoctrine()
    //call the repository of your physician table
    ->getRepository('Bundle:physician')
    ->findBy(['specfk' => $specId]);

    var_dump($allPhysician);
}
```

Comment: @parker Did you create a route for getallphysician? If not do that, if so please post your route config.

Comment: where do I find the route config file. am new to symfony

Comment: @parker pathToYourBunde\Resources\Config\routing.yml

Comment: I can only see services.xml there

Comment: @parker oooh oke. I edited my answer. Do you mind trying that code and going to /physicians/2 in your webbrowser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144169/discussion-between-parker-and-gerjan).

Comment: lets continue in chat

Answer (score 0):

Use the `findBy()` method of the "physician" repository:

(You didn't post your actual entities so I'm guessing the field/entity names.)

```
$spec = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:SpecArea')->find($specId); 

$physicians = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:Physician')->findBy(['spec' => $spec]);
```

You can also use `$specId` ID directly instead of fetching the entire entity from database:

```
    $physicians = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:Physician')->findBy(['spec' => $specId]);
```

See: [Working with Objects - Querying - By Simple Conditions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

Comment: what field do you mean by spec do u mean the foreign key in the physician table

Comment: "specfk".. it's better to mention field names rather than actual database column names when using an ORM